# Quelle serait une variante de « Il n’a pas fini de nous surprendre/épater/faire rire! »

Tags: formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

Dans la mesure du possible, bien sûr, je souhaiterais qu’on me propose une variante de la phrase en objet qui ne fait pas appel au tour « ne pas avoir + finir de ».

Il n’a pas fini de nous…

…surprendre!

…épater!

…faire rire!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Il nous surprendra/épatera encore                                (*On envisage une limite.*)
- Il nous réserve encore des surprises                                               (")
- On est loin de la dernière des surprises qu'il nous réserve         (")
- Il nous surprendra toujours                                                 (*Sans limite*)
- Il nous fera toujours rire                                                              (")

Answer (score 0):

Ça dépend de la nuance voulue, mais moi j'utiliserais :

> Il ne cesse pas de nous surprendre.

Malheureusement, ce n'a pas la même nuance :

> Il n'a pas fini de nous surprendre.

Regarde soit vers un temps future quand il *va* arrêter de surprendre et/ou il fait une description du passé (on pourrait l'utiliser par exemple quand on compte une histoire au sujet d'un ami qui n'a pas arrêté de nous surprendre pendant qu'on était en voyage ensemble)

D'autre part,

> Il ne cesse pas de nous surprendre.

concentre sur l'état présent, voulant dire que maintenant, pendant même qu'on parle, on s'attend à se faire surprendre par la personne.

Autre option, si vous voulez le mettre dans le positif, serait :

> Il continue de nous surprendre.

Encore une fois, c'est dans le temps présent et a plus le sens de « Il ne cesse pas de nous surprendre. »